# Is it OK to leave the thermostat unwired?

Tags: thermostat

So I went to replace the batteries in my thermostat and when I pulled it off I noticed a black wire was unplugged. I'm not sure if it's suppose to be like that or if I accidentally pulled the black wire out since the screws on the backplate were loose. It's a white and black wire. The white wire is still connected to the W and the black wire is not connected. Is it alright to leave it this way until I get back from school? I'm already late trying to figure out where the damn black wire goes. Thanks

Comment: Two wire system wires go to R and W

Comment: The R and Rc are jumped, do I need to power anything down before connecting the black wire? Thanks

Comment: No, R and RC are usually jumpered on a single heating or cooling system. BTW if you leave it unconnected then I don't think anything bad will happen except for the heating system not coming on which may be an issue if it's very cold.

Comment: Alright I've connected the black wire to R leaving it jumpered to RC. Will I die if the wire is in the incorrect spot?

Comment: Nope. You'll die, eventually, regardless of where the wire is, - it's a consequence of being alive, inescapable, inevitable, and unrelated to thermostats.

Comment: Well I'm alive, thanks for the help. Seems to be working, waiting for it to turn off before I leave.

Comment: Oops misread your comment. Typically you want to power down the system before altering the wiring but except for electric baseboard heating the voltage and current are fairly low. There's usually a switch near the boiler or furnace.

Answer (score 1):

The only risk is if you live in a cold climate, your pipes could freeze and burst, flooding your home.  This is unlikely to occur in a few hours, but keep in mind the time of day and the availability of stores and professionals should you need additional supplies or assistance.  If it's -30 out, this isn't something you want to leave broken for 24hours.